# Build CEF on Windows 10

Tags: c++, build, snapshot, chromium-embedded, ninja

The compilation of the CEF in Windows 10 until now has been a week of work and various remediation. Now it seems that I am at the last steps of the compilation but I have a problem not yet solved, Ninja fails at

> [30545/36949] ACTION //tools/v8_context_snapshot:gener..._context_snapshot(//build/toolchain/win:win_clang_x86)
> FAILED: v8_context_snapshot.bin
> C:/code/depot_tools/bootstrap-3_8_0_chromium_8_bin/python/bin/python.exe ../../build/gn_run_binary.py ./v8_context_snapshot_generator --output_file=v8_context_snapshot.bin
> [1203/185351.657:FATAL:com_init_check_hook.cc(159)] Check failed: false. CoCreateInstance appears to be previously patched. <cc cc cc cc cc e9 2b> Attempted to write <e9 80 2f d6 91 eb f9>

My enviroment Windows10, VS 2017 v 15.9.28, Win 10.0.17763 SDK and Ninja.
Does anyone know what it can be?
Thank you very much kind regards

Answer (score 2):

I was finally able to compile CEF with .mp4 support for the chosen version v75. I share with you all the steps necessary to compile in the windows environment.
What's Required for branch 3770 --> Chromium Version v 75.
Win 7+, VS2017 15.7.1+, Win 10.0.17763 SDK, Ninja, at least 8GB of RAM and 40GB of free disk space. Need particular attention to the SDK version, installed it separately and not with Visual Studio, moreover it must necessarily be the one indicated, if there are later versions uninstall them completely.
Install the required Visual Studio sub-components by passing the following arguments to the Visual Studio installer:

```
$ PATH_TO_INSTALLER.EXE ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop ^
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATLMFC ^
--includeRecommended
```

See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding.md#markdown-header-current-release-branches-supported.
For Download and correct build step by step see:https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart
This procedure as it is only the download of the Master proceeds,
If you want to compile a specific branch, compile the path where to download it and modify the update.bat file accordingly.
Set all necessary enviroment variable and restart the PC before all:

- Variable  CEF_USE_GN  value CEF_USE_GN=1
- Variable  GN_DEFINES value Set GN_DEFINES=proprietary_codecs=1 ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
- Variable Path add value of C:\code\depot_tools  your path for folder depot_tools.
- Variable DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN  valore DEPOT_TOOLS_WIN_TOOLCHAIN=0.
  For example for the 3770 branch
  build the path C: \ code \ chromium_git3770

and write in update.bat like:

set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2017 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
python ..\automate\automate-git.py --download-dir=C:\code\chromium_git3770  --depot-tools-dir=C:\code\depot_tools --branch=3770 --no-distrib --no-build

and the Create.bat like:
set CEF_USE_GN=1
set GN_DEFINES=is_official_build=true proprietary_codecs=true ffmpeg_branding=Chrome
set GN_ARGUMENTS=--ide=vs2017 --sln=cef --filters=//cef/*
call cef_create_projects.bat

Resolve error:

- Error on build with Ninja
  try running “gclient runhooks” from the chromium/src directory  always from cmd
  this command renews the files in depot_tools
  on Windows 10 especially there are various problems and various issues (node.js is missing, etc.)
- ImportError: No module named win32file
  Install correct WinApi on python folder.
  C:\code\depot_tools>python -m pip install pywin32
- Error FAILED: v8_context_snapshot.bin
  where suggested running "gn clean" before a full build in all out path to build, after each build with error.
  Wait about 4 hours and you will have your buil.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your detailed process.

In my case, i was able to build with https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/MasterBuildQuickStart

However, i have an error when i try to import the exported CefSharp library from the application that ninja build.
This is the error i have on my application : "Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime.dll'".
Also, with the ninja build, i don't have the same files when i downloaded the library.

Can you tell me how do you export the library ? Thanks :)